# Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Find the number of positive integers $k$ with $1<k<p$, for which $k^2$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $p$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Find the number of positive integers $k$ with $1<k<p$, for which $k^2$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $p$.

I have solved the problem as displayed in the answer posted by me. Is there a more direct and better method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Given that $p$ is an odd prime. We need to find the number of positive integers k with $1<k<p$ such that $k^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p}\implies p|k^2-1\implies p|(k-1)(k+1)\implies p|k-1$ or $p|k+1$.

Case 1 $\left(p|k+1\right)$: Given that $1<k<p\implies 2<k+1<p+1\implies 3\le k+1\le p$. Now it is obvious that, since $p$ is a prime, implies $p\nmid j$, $\forall$ $3\le j<p$. But, $p|p\implies k+1=p\implies k=p-1.$ Therefore, this case yields only one solution, that is $k=p-1$.

Case 2 $\left(p|k-1\right)$: Again we have $1<k<p \implies 0<k-1<p-1 \implies 1\le k-1 \le p-2.$ Again it is obvious that $p\nmid j, \forall$ $1\le j\le p-2$. Therefore, this case yields no solution.

After analyzing all the cases, we can conclude that there is only one positive integer $k$, such that $1<k<p$ and $k^2\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and that positive integer is $k=p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

We need $p$ to divide $k^2-1=(k+1)(k-1)$

But as $k+1-(k-1)=2,p$ must divide exactly one of $k+1,k-1$

Now we need $1<k<p$